# When to use transactions in Spring with Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring-3, spring-transactions, hibernate3

Upgrading my project I'm thinking here about transactions.
Well, the thing is I'm not quite sure **when should I use the transactions** for my Hibernate queries in Spring.
Not that I completely don't understand what transactions are, I guess I do, but
**Do I need to use transactions for a `get*` type queries just setting the `read-only` attribute?**

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <!-- all methods starting with 'get' are read-only -->
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
        <!-- other methods use the default transaction settings -->
        <tx:method name="*" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

Is that efficient for `get*` queries?
Because, as far I think, using transactions should be done like for `CREATE`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and such queries.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539213/why-do-i-need-transaction-in-hibernate-for-read-only-operations

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using transactions is somewhat dependent on the requirement.

Obviously, using transactions on UPDATE and DELETE operations makes sense.  Using transactions on SELECT statements could be useful too if, for example, you needed to lock the record such that another thread/request would not change the read.  This would generally be a business requirement.

At our company we do wrap all statements (i.e. SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE) in a transaction.

In addition, transactional management is really better suited at another layer in addition to the data level.  Generally, transactions would match the business requirement.  For example, if the requirement is to deposit money in an account, then some higher level class/code should be used to mark the entire method as transactional since that specific method needs to be completed as one unit (since there would likely be multiple database calls).

Spring has much to say about transactional management.

Comment: I also normally wrap every business operation that accesses the database in a transaction. Recently I was wondering if this causes any overhead that might slow down the application. In such a case, would it make sense to use a transaction only for create, delete, update?

Comment: Our company requires us to commit after every transaction, even SELECT statements.  I could certainly see where wrapping only UPDATE statements would create less overhead.

Answer (score 3):

A good rule is to manage transactions at an application level above DAO. This way, if you have a data access operation A that some times need to be executed in own transaction and sometimes should join the existing transaction, you wouldn't have to jump through the hoops. Combine this approach with managing transactions (and Hibernate sessions) via AOP and watch your code grow more understandable and maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/florinlazar/archive/2005/10/04/476775.aspx) seems like a fairly decent answer of why you should.  However, [this](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/Transactionless.html) gives some reasons not to.  Basically, it you want to use them when data could end up in a bad state if your modifications are not completed.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question about getters:

If you use an AOP transaction with readOnly true, *and* you properly set your JPA dialect to hibernate, Spring will put your Hibernate Session into no-flush mode.  That can add up to substantial performance improvements for high volume operations by eliminating needless dirty-checks.  So it is worthwhile in that regard.