# Define methods for not running in a transation when using Springs´ transaction management together with hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

i am currently writing a spring-webmvc app and some days ago, my first problem was that i didn´t know how to use transactions with Hibernate and Spring. Now everything works, a transactionsmanager is up living and i can successfully work with transactions.

This is the part of my Java based spring config:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "de.macomp.maipds" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MainConfigLib {

    ...

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager manager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
        return manager;
    }
}
```

So, when i want a method in my service- or dao-layer to run in a transaction i simply annotate it with @Transactional and everything´s ok. 
My problem is, when i want a service method *not* to run in a transaction, i am getting the following error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
```

The code where this happens looks like:

```
    ...
    @Override
    public Publisher findByName(String name) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        //bam!
        ...
```

Can i "force" my environment somehow to give me a "non-transactional" session?!
The transactionManager property of the sessionFactory in my DAO is null.

Adding @Transactional to "findByName" solves the problem, but for this method no transaction is needed...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transaction is needed, you can mark this method as `read-only`

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Publisher findByName(String name) {
   ...
}
```

From [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/transaction.html):

> Read-only status: a read-only transaction does not modify any data.
>   Read-only transactions can be a useful optimization in some cases
>   (such as when using Hibernate).

From [JBoss Wiki](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/Non-transactionalDataAccessAndTheAuto-commitMode)

> Many application developers think they can talk to a database outside
>   of a transaction. This obviously isn’t possible; no SQL statement can
>   be send to a database outside of a database transaction. The term
>   nontransactional data access means there are no explicit transaction
>   boundaries, no system transaction, and that the behavior of data
>   access is that of the autocommit mode. It doesn’t mean no physical
>   database transactions are involved.

More:

- [Why do I need Transaction in Hibernate for read only operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539213/why-do-i-need-transaction-in-hibernate-for-read-only-operation)
- [Use of implicit transactions is discouraged](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/hprof/learn/alert/donotuseimplicittransactions)

Comment: ok. but it still opens a transaction... i want to run queries directly without having my orm to open / begin a transaction and finally commit it. but if i correctly understood the first answer from your posted question link, the reason for my problem is hibernates internal behaviour...

Comment: I have updated my answer: "no SQL statement can be send to a database outside of a database transaction"

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
   <property name="sessionFactory">
       <ref bean="mySessionFactory"/>
   </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

add above definition, and make your service or dao class marked with @Transactional annotation.

Comment: hm. i think this is not necessary because i configuered my app with Java based Spring Configuration

Comment: You can enable transactions with JavaConfig (@EnableTransactionManagement), this is not needed.