# Is `session.getTransaction().commit();` required in hibernate while fetching data

Tags: hibernate

I would like to know

Is  `session.getTransaction().commit();` required in hibernate while fetching data

```
private List listEvents() {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List result = session.createQuery("from Event").list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return result;
    }
```

This example is taken from http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#tutorial-firstapp-firstclass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need a transaction even for read operation and it should be committed as per the hibernate documentation.

Here are the details:

[13.2. Database transaction demarcation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch13.html#transactions-demarcation)

> Database, or system, transaction boundaries are always necessary. No
>   communication with the database can occur outside of a database
>   transaction (this seems to confuse many developers who are used to the
>   auto-commit mode). **Always use clear transaction boundaries, even for
>   read-only operations.** Depending on your isolation level and database
>   capabilities this might not be required, but there is no downside if
>   you always demarcate transactions explicitly. Certainly, a single
>   database transaction is going to perform better than many small
>   transactions, even for reading data.

In case of plain JDBC, the auto-commit is enabled by default. Here are the details for it:

[Disabling Auto-Commit Mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html#disable_auto_commit)

> **When a connection is created, it is in auto-commit mode. This means
>   that each individual SQL statement is treated as a transaction and is
>   automatically committed right after it is executed.** (To be more
>   precise, the default is for a SQL statement to be committed when it is
>   completed, not when it is executed. A statement is completed when all
>   of its result sets and update counts have been retrieved. In almost
>   all cases, however, a statement is completed, and therefore committed,
>   right after it is executed.)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK: in most cases it doesn't matter. Both approaches (commit/ rollback) are valid.

But the recommended way is to commit, because that relational databases are performance optimized for the most common expected case which is **commit**, not rollback.

---

UPDATE:
You can take a look at following [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13540484/1037316) if you are wondering why to start transaction at all.

Comment: But why it is needed in fetch

Comment: It varies. Good practice is to open transaction for every DB operation. Also transaction is useful to ensure that no other transaction added data that makes your view inconsistent.