# Usage of @Transactional in service, when method only fetches data from DB.

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

I just found a piece of code which looks as follow:

```
@Transactional
public List<Foo> giveMeFooMatchingSomeConstraints(Long param1, String param2) {
 List<Bar> bars = barDao.findBars(param1, param2);
 List<Foo> foos = fooDao.findFoosByBarIds(barService.getIds(bars));
 return foos; 
}
```

I'm just curious what's the purpose of using @Transactional in case when a method only fetches data and doesn't modify them. Is such an approach like above ok?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I need Transaction in Hibernate for read only operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539213/why-do-i-need-transaction-in-hibernate-for-read-only-operation)

Comment: for fetching data, no need to annotate with Transactional, whenever we have to persist multiple table that time only can use Transactional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it makes sense when you aren't using `Open*InView` and working with lazy relations within your method.

Say we have these entities bounded with one-to-many relation:

```
@Entity(name = "user")
static class User extends AbstractPersistable<String> {
    private String username;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true) //by default fetching is lazy
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_user_roles"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return this.roles;
    }
}

@Entity(name = "role")
static class Role extends AbstractPersistable<String> {
    private String name;

    private Role() {
    }

    public Role(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

a repository to access them:

```
interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, String> {}
```

and a service for some data manipulation - retrieve all users, iterate trough them and grab all the roles:

```
@Service
static class UserService {
    private final UserDao userDao;

    UserService(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Transactional // <---
    public Set<String> findUserRoles() {
        final List<User> users = this.userDao.findAll();
        return users.stream()
                .flatMap(user -> user.roles.stream())
                .map(Role::getName)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

Remove `@Transactional` to see `LazyInitializationException` with `no Session` message, since nobody have opened it.

To avoid confusions in such cases it is better to explicitly mark transaction as read-only:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
```

So reader will know that this method have no intention to modify any data, but transaction (session) is still required.

[Full example](https://gist.github.com/bohdanlevchenko/1111088a491d145a153b4604c51a4de3).

Comment: Great explanation, the reason of using @Transactional in this case is clear to me now. I like the example the example you provided, thanks!