# Why we need @Transaction Attribute in spring for only select statement - NO ddl in service layer

Tags: spring, concurrency, spring-transactions, transaction-isolation

I read multiple threads but I didn't get the answer to why we need to use `@Transaction` attribute for the select query.

Assume we don't have any other DDL statements just plain select statements which read data and displays on UI.

Transaction attribute provides isolation, so If I don't use `@Transaction` attribute it may possible it will show me the most recent data which will be good, isn't it?

Could you please provide me any reference article link , share your knowledge, pros and cons for only `@Transaction` use with Select statements.

Comment: Which Database are you using? Are you using JPA?

Comment: We are using spring jdbc and we are putting the @transaction at method level not the class level.

Comment: This might be a good read for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539213/why-do-i-need-transaction-in-hibernate-for-read-only-operations

Comment: And what database?

Comment: We are using oracle as database